# Remove separator from last list item but with after as well

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I'm adding a separator to a series of list items using CSS `:after`, but I *don't* want it on the `:last-child` and I can't for the life of me remember how I got it to work last time I did something like this (it's been awhile...sorry).

Here's what I have:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  &:after {
    content: '|';
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
  &:last-child {
    content: '';
  }
}
```

Hope that make sense? I can't remember if I need to structure this differently or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `:not(:last-child):after` to select all elements apart from the last child.
As so:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '|';
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: BOOM! Yeah, that was it. I do remember that at the time I had it structured differently, but I forgot about the :not that you can use. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could be of help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `content: none;` to override it.

Or you can add it to `&:not(:last-child):after` instead of overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is calling `:last-child` on the element like so: `li:last-child`

You need to do something like

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  &:after {
    content: '|';
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
  &:last-child {
    &:after {
        content: '';
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.